# POST request working on Postman but not on Expo

Tags: node.js, postman, expo

I implemented an e-mail OTP verification using Node-JS for an app. When I tested it with Postman, it worked properly and I got the OTP in my email, meaning the logic is probably correct. But when I run the app with Expo Client, I am not getting the email.

Please tell me where the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

Since the request worked just fine with postman perhaps this is a CORS issue.

Have you enabled CORS in your application?

https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Install the package then add:

```
app.use(cors())
```

This should make it work just fine with localhost.

If this is not the issue you should probably provide more info on the problem such as error codes returned by your application.